# How to create a xamarin container with thick left border with frames and stackLayout

Tags: xamarin.forms

I'm trying to create a xamarin form UI as in the below snapshot.

[image]

I'm trying with the following code,

```
var reviewLabel = new Label
            {
                TextColor = Constants.MMSGAlertColor,
                Text = "Select the benefit to findout more",
                FontSize = 12
            };

            var alertLayout = new StackLayout
            {
                HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.FillAndExpand,
                VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.FillAndExpand,
                BackgroundColor = Constants.MMSGAlertBackgroundColor,

            };

            var alertContentLayout = new StackLayout
            {
                Margin = new Thickness(8, 0, 0, 0),
                HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.FillAndExpand,
                VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.FillAndExpand,
                BackgroundColor = Constants.MMSGAlertBackgroundColor
            };

            var warningBoxView = new BoxView
            {
                BackgroundColor = Constants.MMSGAlertColor
            };

            alertLayout.Children.Add(warningBoxView);
            alertLayout.Children.Add(alertContentLayout);
            alertContentLayout.Children.Add(reviewLabel);


            var frame = new Frame
            {
                Padding = 16,
                OutlineColor = Constants.MMSGAlertBorderColor,
                BackgroundColor = Constants.MMSGAlertBackgroundColor,
                HasShadow = false,
                Content = alertLayout,
                HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.Fill,
                VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.FillAndExpand
            };

            frame.SetBinding(IsVisibleProperty, "IsPaymentPlanEnding");

            var rowLayout = new StackLayout
            {

            };

            rowLayout.Children.Add(frame);
            rowLayout.Children.Add(rowGrid);
```

But the current UI is coming up as below,

[image]

THe result output is coming up with a thick border with padding inside the frame.

But i trying to generate a UI with thick 8px strip to the left of my container.

Is there a way i can create a border with frame with left thickness of 8px and rest 1px.

Comment: Is it fine, if I can provide you code in XAML?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please see the below XAML code. Add the proper color required as I used my own colors. Also if you want, you can rewrite the same in the code behind.

```
<Frame HasShadow="False" BackgroundColor="Pink" Padding="1" CornerRadius="3" VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand" >
            <Grid BackgroundColor="White" Padding="0">
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="10"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <BoxView BackgroundColor="Red" Grid.Column="0"/>
                <StackLayout Padding="15,20,0,20"  Grid.Column="1" Spacing="20">
                    <Label Text="Please review" TextColor="Red" FontSize="13" FontAttributes="Bold"/>
                    <Label Text="Select the benefit above to find more" TextColor="Red" FontSize="13"/>
                </StackLayout>
            </Grid>
        </Frame>
```